# Mobile doesnt let me use already logged in accounts | firebase | ionic | android

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-authentication

I made an awesome google login for my ionic app using firebase, on desktop everything works like a charm. but on mobile it keeps asking me to enter my password while i'm logged in to google on my device. it is possible to make it use already logged in accounts because i have seen it at alot of app's

I already used the whitelist plugin to whitelist auth.firebase.com

Is there any documentation for this? or any solution? (im using `$authWithOAuthPopup("google")`)

Example:
[image]

Comment: Do you mean if you're logged in on Desktop that your mobile device is also logged in?

Comment: nope i sorry probably i formulated it wrong, i want to let mobile behave like the app on desktop, i want it to let me select from already logged in accounts on my device. and not need to enter my gmail email and password